# Android linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd() not working for chat show last element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I'm working on a chat application. Now, while fetching messages from the back-end for the first time, i want my Linear Layout pointer to move to the last message in the list, so that the user always sees the latest messages on opening the chat fragment. 
This is my code:

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(homeScreenActivity);
   linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
   linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
   chatRecycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use **chatRecycler.scrollToPosition(chatRecycler.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);**
after fetching data.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know the when data is entered, you can make `addOnLayoutChangeListener` on your recycler view.

**And in `addOnLayoutChangeListener`**

```
chatRecycler.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v,
                                       int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                                       int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                if (bottom < oldBottom) {
                    chatRecycler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            recycler_discussion.scrollToPosition(
                                    recycler_discussion.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
                        }
                    }, 50);
                }
            }
        });
```